# Get list of folder paths of subfolders of a given location

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch script to get a list of all subfolders (not recursive!) of the directories located in a specific given location, for which the directory names start with one of a few predefined values. The list should only contain absolute paths. I can't use Powershell or other additional tools.

```
@echo off
set "yourDir=C:\FileStore"
for %%b in ("AB*","FG*") do (
    for /d %%a in ("%yourDir%\%%b") do (
        echo %%~fa
    )
)
```

This results in an empty list and doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for %%b` loop in your code searches for *files* matching the patterns `AB*` and `FG*` in the current directory.

You could do this:

```cmd
@echo off
set "yourDir=C:\FileStore"
pushd "%yourDir%" && (
    for /D %%a in ("AB*","FG*") do (
        echo %%~fa
    )
    popd
)
```

You might alternatively write `"%yourDir%\AB*","%yourDir%\FG*"` behind `in` but using [`pushd`](https://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html) prevents you from having to redundantly specify the root directory.

Or you could do that:

```cmd
@echo off
set "yourDir=C:\FileStore"
for %%b in ("AB","FG") do (
    for /D %%a in ("%yourDir%\%%~b*") do (
        echo %%~fa
    )
)
```

Since there are no wildcards in the `in` clause of the `for %%b` loop any more, the items are returned untouched without searching the file system for matching files. The `for /D %%a` loop now contains the wildcard, so it actually searches matching immediate sub-directories.